# Can someone explain why animation-fill-mode: forwards stopped working for me

Tags: javascript, css, animation

**UPDATE: PARTIALLY SOLVED!**  By changing the position property of #span1 and #span2 to static (instead of absolute), I got the spans to visually chain rather than overlap. But now, the functionality of `animation-fill-mode: forwards` seems to have been overridden; at the end of the animation, the whole word jumps back to the first keyframe instead of staying at the last one.

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/parola/uzwyhu9q/4/

[I've updated the code below and changed the title of the question, which is now about `animation-fill-mode`]

HTML:

```
<p></p>
<button onclick="startAnimation();">Run animation</button>

<section class="span-wrapper">
    <div id="span-words"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.span-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px;   
    font-size: 48px;
}

#span1{
    position: static;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: slideToRight_1 2s ease-in-out 1 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: slideToRight_1 2s ease-in-out 1 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#span2{ 
    position: static;
    color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: slideToRight_1 2s ease-in-out 1 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: slideToRight_1 2s ease-in-out 1 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slideToRight_1 {
   0%   {  transform: translateX(-100px) ; }
   100% {  transform: translateX(300px) ; }
}
@keyframes slideToRight_1 {
   0%   {  transform: translateX(-100px) ; }
   100% {  transform: translateX(300px) ; }
}
```

JS:

```
function startAnimation() {

var word = {
    fullWord: "breakfast",
    piece1:  "break",
    piece2a: "fast",
}

document.querySelector('#span-words').innerHTML = '<span id="span1"></span><!----><span id="span2"></span>';

document.querySelector('#span1').innerHTML = word.piece1;
document.querySelector('#span2').innerHTML = word.piece2a;

}
```

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/parola/uzwyhu9q/4/

Comment: You should only use `-webkit-` extension in properties of `@-webkit-keyframes`, but not inside `@keyframes`. Otherwise, it won't work on other browsers like Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, Oriol. I've removed the -webkit- extensions inside @keyframes and have updated the jsfiddle link. Now I get some animation in Firefox but not what I expect.

Comment: Through experimentation, I've answered my original question, but it introduced a new problem. Please see new title and question content above.